# Updating PixMaps based on ComboBox selections in PyQt

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, pixmap

I have a QComboBox populated with text entries (e.g., "apple", "orange", "banana"). I need to update a QPixMap located in a cell of a gridlayout whenever one of the listed items is selected. So, if you select "apple", the apple.jpg would display within the specified ComboBox's PixMap cell.

I was trying to avoid a long list of manually entered "if/else" statements in the code because I am going to have many combo boxes with several options (eventually from database queues) and many image cells (one for each combo box).

Creating static PixMaps in QLabel containers within the grid, I can handle. As well as the ComboBoxes themselves.

### Edit:

I have tried to implement the code suggested by Subin Gopi (I have only included relevant sections):

```
self.fruit_list = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']

self.fruit_combo = QtGui.QComboBox()
self.fruit_combo.addItems(self.fruit_list)

def image_update(self, qcombobox, qlabel):
    image_path ="c :/images"
    current_item = str(qcombobox.currentText())
    current_image = '%s/%s.jpg' %(image_path, current_item)
    qlabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(current_image))

self.fruit_image = QtGui.QLabel(self)
self.grid.addWidget(self.fruit_image, 1, 1) 
self.fruit_combo.currentIndexChanged[str].connect(lambda: 
                  self.image_update(self.fruit_combo, self.fruit_image)
```

This doesn't seem to be allowing the image to update. Not sure if I am just making a blatant mistake somewhere or what.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is this a poorly asked question?

Comment: Some illustrations of what you were trying to avoid would have been helpful.  It does however look as if you have attracted an answer.  Once again Welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one small updates on your code, that is image name  (e.g., "apple", "orange", "banana") and QComboBox item name should be same. So you can avoid if else statements. Check the example code.

```
QComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect (imageUpdate)
imagePath       = 'C:/images'

def imageUpdate :
    currentItem     = str (QComboBox.currentText ())
    currentImage    = '%s/%s.jpg'% (imagePath, currentItem) 
    QLabel.setPixmap (QtGui.QPixmap (currentImage ))
```

Comment: Subin, I have tried to implement this code and provided an example in my edit of the original post above. It doesn't seem to be working as expected. Perhaps I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Nevermind, there was something else in a different part of the code which was causing issues. This works excellently. Thanks!